# Почему изображения при импорте товаров из .yml файла перестают загружаться?

Tags: php, xml, laravel, yml

В проекте на Laravel 5.4 использую очереди и супервизор для импорта товаров из файла формата ".yml". При создании очередей, передаю переменную с номером товара с которого надо начать импорт, чтобы скрипт не висел долго. Таким образом, если в файле 100 000 товаров, создается 100 очередей по 1000 товаров. Все импортируется корректно за исключением изображений.

Примерно на 30-40 тысячи изображений они перестают загружаться на сервер. В БД корректно записывается название изображения и путь к нему, никаких ошибок при работе не возникает.

[image: Так эта проблема отображается на сайте]

Считываю файл XMLReader и c помощью simplexml_import_dom разбираю товар. Скачиваю изображение используя:

```
move_uploaded_file($link, $path);
```

Где $link, соответственно ссылка на сторонний ресурс.Все они без каких либо проблем открываются в браузере.

Пробовал делать загрузку через curl, результат еще хуже, даже на маленьком файле более половины изображений не загружаются. На диске появляются пустые файлы по 0 байт.

```
public function uploadImage($link, $path){
    $ch = curl_init ($link);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    $raw=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    if(file_exists($path)){
        unlink($path);
    }
    $fp = fopen($path,'x');
    fwrite($fp, $raw);
    fclose($fp);       
}
```

Добавив такую конструкцию в функцию загрузки

```
if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
    {
        dd('Ошибка curl: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
```

я получаю вывод `Ошибка curl: <url> malformed`. С чем это может быть связано?

Буду благодарен за любую помощь и предложения.

Comment: По-хорошему `move_uploaded_file` не должен скачивать сторонний ресурс :-) curl конечно предпочтительней, так как позволяет легко посмотреть ошибки возникающие при скачивании (возможно у вас есть какие-то лимиты на сервере и попытки скачивать картинки просто режутся или сеть тупит). В базу-то вы $path записываете?

Comment: Что странно, при использовании curl я получаю множество пустых изображений, по 0 байт. Но никаких ошибок я не получаю. До `move_uploaded_file` использовал `copy()`, результат тот же. Отсутствие ошибок пугает меня больше всего, я не понимаю, что не так. `$path` записывается в базу к модели товара, используется потом при выводе изображений на странице.

Comment: Либо что-то не так с url (может пробелы лишние или ещё что) либо сервер блокирует частые запросы

Comment: @Nick привел ссылку из xml элемента к строке и обернул в trim(), не помогло. `$link = trim($link->__toString());`

Comment: Так же попробовал ставить `sleep(0.5);`. При том, это все на файле из 500 товаров. `move_uploaded_file` начинал загружать пустые изображения только на 30-40 тысячах. А через `curl` даже в таком маленьком файле более половины изображений приходит пустыми в 0 байт.

Comment: Обратите внимание, что есть варианты, когда сторонний сервер ответит вам пустым телом, и при этом это не будет ошибкой curl. Проверяйте код HTTP-ответа, логируйте ответ если тело пустое и смотрите, что там не так. Если вы парсите сторонний сайт, то возможно вы стлкнулись с механизмом противодействия парсингу. Кстати, sleep принимает целое число.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин использовал и sleep и usleep c разными значениями. В любом случае, это не решает проблемы. Спасибо за ваши ответы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что я передавал в функцию `uploadImage` `SimpleXMLelement` содержащий строку с `url` адресом. `Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed` и поэтому `curl` создавал пустой файл, ведь `url` поступал к нему некорректно.

Приводя передаваемую `$link` к строке с помощью `(string)` перед передачей в функцию, проблема больше не возникала.

P.S. А вот почему изображения переставали загружаться с помощью `move_uploaded_file` я разобраться не сумел.